# Захват изображения рабочего стола активного монитора

Tags: c, winapi, screenshots

Если к ПК подключено более одного монитора (например, ноутбук с дополнительным экраном, подключенным по D-SUB или HDMI), как захватить экран именно на том, на котором сейчас курсор? Или может можно как-то сразу все мониторы захватить в индивидуальный буфер для каждого?

Захват изображения основного рабочего стола выполняю так:

```
unsigned int Screen::GetMetrics(unsigned int *width, unsigned int *height){
    *width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    *width-= (*width%4);
    *height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    *height-= (*height%4);
    return (*width * *height * 3);
}
unsigned int Screen::Grab(unsigned char **frame, unsigned int *timing){
    // Defining screen dimensions
    unsigned int start = GetTickCount();
    unsigned int width, height, size = GetMetrics(&width, &height);
    unsigned char *framebuf = nullptr;
    if( size ){
        // Creating contexts
        HDC ScreenDC = GetDC(0);
        HDC MemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ScreenDC);
        // Lock object (for multithread use)
        WaitForSingleObject(M_Screen, INFINITE);
        // Filling image header struct
        BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
        BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
        BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width * height * BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount / 8;
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(ScreenDC,&BitmapInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void**)&framebuf,0,0);
        SelectObject(MemoryDC, hBitmap);
        BitBlt(MemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, ScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        // Get cursor info
        CURSORINFO CursorInfo;
        CursorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CursorInfo);
        if( GetCursorInfo(&CursorInfo) ){
            ICONINFO IconInfo;
            GetIconInfo(CursorInfo.hCursor, &IconInfo);
            DeleteObject(IconInfo.hbmColor);
            DeleteObject(IconInfo.hbmMask);
            DrawIcon(MemoryDC, CursorInfo.ptScreenPos.x - IconInfo.xHotspot, CursorInfo.ptScreenPos.y - IconInfo.yHotspot, CursorInfo.hCursor);
        }
        ReleaseDC(NULL,ScreenDC);
        DeleteDC(MemoryDC);
        // Writing data and clearing buffers
        memcpy(*frame, framebuf, size);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        ReleaseMutex(M_Screen);
    }
    // if need to know capture elapsed time
    if( timing != nullptr){*timing = GetTickCount() - start;}
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EnumDisplayMonitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610(v=vs.85).aspx) поможет Вам определить координаты каждого подключенного монитора в системе.

```
BOOL CALLBACK monEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData){

    // lprcMonitor - координаты монитора hMonitor на HDC

    return TRUE;
}
...
EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, monEnumProc, 0);
```

А [CreateDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490(v=vs.85).aspx) позволяет захватить сразу все мониторы в одном HDC, в котором эти координаты актуальны.

```
hAllDTopsDC   = ::CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);

// hAllDTopsDC - HDC, с которого можно делать скриншот любого монитора

::DeleteDC(hAllDTopsDC);
```

Посмотрите для полноценного примера исходники [Monitors Viewer](https://github.com/mega-t72/mv), который как раз следит за мышью и показывает содержимое активного монитора.

Comment: Впервые увидел в Вашем коде такую конструкцию - `for( auto i : mons )`. Подскажите пожалуйста это из какого стандарта?

Comment: Это [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), из `С++11`

Comment: Не знаете случайно, как получать монитор на котором фокус? С мышкой всё получилось, но можно alt-tab на окно, расположенное на другом мониторе, оставив мышь на первом. И тогда можно с клавиатуры управлять окном на втором мониторе, а транслироваться он не будет. Может можно по аналогии с мышью получать координаты, в которых активна клавиатура?

Comment: Ну да, по аналогии можно и за фокусом следить: `GetFocus` вернет окно с фокусом, а `GetWindowRect` вернет его координаты, а `IntersectRect` позволяет получить результат пересечения прямоугольников: надо перебрать все мониторы и вызвать для каждого `IntersectRect`, посчитать их площади. Сфокусированный монитор тот, площадь пересечения которого с окном фокуса больше. Только не все так просто: `GetFocus` работает только в текущем потоке, т.е. надо по таймеру аттачиться (`AttachThreadInput`) к потоку foreground-окна (`GetForegroundWindow`) и проверять его фокус.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за помощь!